# Как сделать роутинг REACT без перезагрузки страницы?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

```
<BrowserRouter>
      <div className="App">
        <Header/>
        <Route path = "/search" component = {Search}/>
        <Route path = "/my-list" component = {MyList}/>
      </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
```

Таким образом у меня организован роутинг в приложении, как сделать так, чтобы при переадресации не обновлялась страница? Мне это нужно, чтобы мой store Redux не обнулялся при переадресации, а оставался в своем состоянии

Comment: <NavLink to='/search'/>
...
https://reactrouter.com/web/api/BrowserRouter